# Modifying the prototype of an object for the entire project

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, browserify, commonjs

I'm using Browserify for my project, but I think this question also impacts development in NodeJS as well. I'm writing a Backbone / Marionette project and I want to override the `sync` method for the entire project. For example, I want to use the Backbone.dualStorage.

When working in the global scope it all made sense to me. You import Backbone with a `script` tag first, then import the dualsync script next to override methods.

Right now I modified the Backbone.dualStorage to export a function which takes `Backbone` and `_` as inputs:

```
module.exports = function(Backbone, _) {

   // It has some special methods for handling local data
   Backbone.Collection.prototype.syncDirty = function(options) {
   };


   // It stores the original Backbone.sync
   backboneSync = Backbone.DualStorage.originalSync = Backbone.sync;

   // Builds a specy dualsync method
   // Then it overrides it
   Backbone.sync = dualsync;

   // Then my modification was to return the new Backbone object with the
   // prototypes modified...
   return Backbone;
};
```

And I import it with

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var _ = require('lodash');
Backbone = require('my-custom-backbone-dualstorage')(Backbone, _);
```

If I call the require on this more than once I get a an error stating that I've got a stack overflow since it creates an infinite loop of the new dualsync calling the old sync, which calls dualsync etc). So now I'm not sure when and where I need to `require` this module I've made. This approach feels hacky.

But I have other reasons that I might want to modify the prototypes of other modules I have. I might want to turn off local syncing entirely:

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.local = false;
```

But where in the project would I do this? Doesn't browserify keep declarations local to the module scope? How do I make sure this change is made throughout the project? What's the best practice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by *Doesn't browserify keep declarations local to the module scope?*, Browserify has the same notion of scope as regular plain Javascript. If you meant *Does browserify create a clone of the thing I import?* then the answer is no.
When you `require('backbone')` in two different modules you still get the same instance of Backbone.

For solving your problem with having a plugin get initialized more than once the approach I take is to require all modules and one-off functions I need in my applications main file. I have one file that kicks everything else off, and that's the same file I use as argument when running browserify.

If you're running from the command line with

```
$ browserify app.js > bundle.js
```

or using Grunt with

```
browserify: {
    app: {
        src: ['src/main/app.js'],
        dest: 'app/app.js'
    }
}
```

Or whichever way you're using it, as long as you make sure to target a single file and let browserify figure out the rest then put your "application-wide" setup in that file, wether that be importing Backbone plugins, overriding sync, running Modernizr or anything else.

If you have split the applications into modules, and you have plugins that you only want to run if a certain module is included, then put it in that module's "main file" instead.